# Smart Mailbox -- Google Folder Doesn't Work

Tags: mail.app, gmail, catalina

I have a folder on 3 different email servers that contains notifications of forum replies.  I want to use a Smart Mailbox to view them all in one place.  However, when I go to set this up the Smart Mailbox won't save a folder within my GMail account, only that ONE GMail account.  I have 2 other GMail accounts that work just fine.

So I select the mailbox.
[image: Selecting the Mailbox]

See, it is selected, and now I save it.
[image: Selected the Mailbox]

Once saved, I go back in, and now no mailbox is selected.
[image: No Box Selected]

I really don't know what else to try, this isn't a deal breaker but ALL of my other accounts work.  I've tried deleting my Google accounts from the computer (and iCloud) then loading them back but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was in the fact that my Apple ID has been around for a long time and was the same email address as my GMail account.  I had to go into Apple's site, manage my ID, and then change my Apple ID to its associated iCloud email address.  Then I had to sign out of my Apple ID and back in on my Mac.  The confusion within Mail seemed to be rooted in the fact that it couldn't tell the two accounts apart in the filters since they had the same email address even though I could get mail on my iCloud account without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to TitanShadow for his reply.  I addressed the issue of my icloud and Gmail accounts having the same gmail.com email address by turning off mail for my iCloud account since I never use it for mail. Once I did that, the problem was solved.  This was easier than having to reset my Apple ID to my icloud email address.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/342758)